# SQL Server cannot connect to localhost:1433

Tags: sql-server

I have checked the above post

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver16

and I am sure my SQL Server is listening on port 1433.

But when I login through ssms, in server name, if I use

```
localhost:1433
```

an error will be thrown, but if I just use

```
localhost
```

then I can login successfully, why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mind to share *what* error you get? And what *exactly* did you enter in your connection window?

Comment: 1433 is the default port so the port specification of 1433 is redundant. The connection will succeed with or without port 1433 specified if SQL Server is listening on the port. Note you need to use a comma, not colon.

Comment: I believe for SQL Server, you need to separate the machine name and port number with a **comma** - try this: `localhost,1433`

Comment: yes, if use comma, connect successfully, thanks.